# How to change from .show( ) to .reveal( )?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change the `.show()` in my code to `.reveal()`, and I can't seem how to do this properly. No errors are being generated, as nothing is happening when I select `day_listing_mobile` `<span>`s

**Here is my JavaScript Code**:

```
(function($) {
    var isMobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));  
    if (isMobile) {
        $('.event_list').hide(); // setting display:none; on all .event_list <ul> elements

        // attach click event to the <span class="day_listing"> elements
        $('.day_listing_mobile').click(function() {
            var $eventList = $(this).sibling('.event_list');

            $('.event_list').hide(); // again hide all possibly shown ones before opening the selected one

            $eventList.show(); // setting display:block on sibling <ul> of clicked <span>

            $('#myMobileModal').reveal();
        });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

**Here is what I'm hiding and wanting to reveal**:

```
{cal_cell_content}<span class="day_listing_mobile">{day}</span><div id="myMobileModal" class="reveal-modal"><ul class="event_list">{content}</ul></div>{/cal_cell_content}
            {cal_cell_content_today}<span class="day_listing_mobile" id="today_listing">{day}</span><div id="myMobileModal" class="reveal-modal"><ul class="event_list">{content}</ul></div>{/cal_cell_content_today}
```

The above code is generating `<ul>`s using CodeIgniter's Calendar class that I'm `.hide()`ing on mobile devices, and that I'm wanting to eventually `.reveal()` instead of `.show()`.

**Here is how `.reveal()` works**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#myButton').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
      $('#myModal').reveal();
     });
});
</script>
```

([more information on Reveal by Zurb](http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin))

**Disclaimer**: I'm new to web development, and suck at anything JavaScript related.

Comment: what did you try, and what errors did you see?

Comment: Can you post your markup? I am not sure what you are trying to pop with reveal()

Comment: Question has been updated for greater clarity.

Comment: Try using a Javascript Debugger (Firefox, Chrome Web Inspector, IE's stuff). You'll at least see `$eventList.show();` is invalid.

Comment: see my fiddle, works there. Note that jquery has a .sibling*s* property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**html**

```
{cal_cell_content}
<span class="day_listing_mobile">{day}</span>
<div id="myMobileModal" class="reveal-modal">
    <ul class="event_list">{content}</ul>
</div>
<a id="myButton" data-reveal-id="myModal" href="javascript://">myButton</a>
{/cal_cell_content}
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.day_listing_mobile').click(function(e) {
        var $eventList = $(this).siblings('.event_list');
        $('.event_list').hide();
        $eventList.show();
        $('#myMobileModal').reveal();
    });
});
```

**css**

// from reveal.css (make sure to include it)

```
.reveal-modal {
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px;
    width: 520px;
    background: #eee url(modal-gloss.png) no-repeat -200px -80px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 101;
    padding: 30px 40px 34px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    }
```

**fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/c4urself/EUPYT/